# Run Geolocation on DalvikVM

Tags: android, dalvik

I know that is possible to run a simple(f.e. HelloWorld) java programms with dalvikvm on Android. I want  to start a simple Geolocation App, but what is with Context? I became just Context don´t found Exception. Does it means that there are no Context for jars, what are started with dalvikvm? Exist some possibilities  to run something like  L`ocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);` on dalvikvm and is it generally possible to run some of the standard android function (like Internet or SMS) with dalvikvm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you mentioned, you can run a simple java program from a terminal. However, you can't run an Android application like that. You can however send an intent from the terminal using the `am` command, which you can use to start an activity/service/broadcast receiver.

So one possible way to do what you want would be to develop a simple android service and install it on your phone, and then start it using `am startservice <intent>`.